# Display 5 different values from popup to 5 different input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Currently I am creating a HTML form for the purpose of purchasing goods.

I have 5 fields which are: "username", "email", "division code", "department code" and "position". When I click on the button below the checkboxes, the 5 data fields should appear in the textboxes. Unfortunately, it failed. when I click the checkbox it shows username only in the 5 fields. I expect that the problem came from JavaScript.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="" ><r>* </r>Requestor Name :</label>
<a href="addRequestor" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRequestor">
<button class="form-control2" style="width: 7%">
<textarea rows="3" cols="40" class="form-control2" id="PRRqName" name="RequestName" required="true" placeholder=""> </textarea> </div>
                              
 <br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="" style="color: green;">Email Address :</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control2" name="RequestMail" id="PRRqMail" readonly value="" style="width: 60%; border-color: grey;">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Division :</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control2" name="RequestDivision" id="PRRqDivi" readonly value="" 
style="width: 60%; border-color: grey;">
</div>   
                         
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Department :</label>   
<input type="text" class="form-control2" name="RequestDept" id="PRRqDept" readonly value="" 
style="width: 60%; border-color: grey;">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Position :</label>   
<input type="text" class="form-control2" name="RequestPosi" id="PRRqPosi" readonly value="" 
style="width: 60%; border-color: grey;">
</div>
```

here is my php code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addRequestor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="min-width: 70%">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Requestor Name</h5>
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
</button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
<div class="card-header py-3">
<h8 class="mb-4" style="color: black"><small> Choose the right Requestor Name</small></h8>
</div>

<div class="card-body align-items-center">
<div class="row no-gutters " >
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="display table table-bordered table-sm" id="addRequestor" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead style="background: #D5CE58">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Requestor Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Division Code</th>
<th>Department Code</th>
<th>Position</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="download-forms-table-tbody">

<?php
$query = "SELECT [User].[Name], [User].[DiviCodeU], [User].[Position], [User].[Email], [Department].[DeptCode]
FROM [Department] JOIN [User] 
ON [Department].[DivCode] = [User].[DiviCodeU]";
$result=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
$Name= $data['Name'];
$Email= $data['Email'];
$DiviCodeU= $data['DiviCodeU'];
$DiviCode= $data['DeptCode'];
$Position= $data['Position'];
echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' value ='$Name'/></center></td>";
echo "<td>$Name</td>";
echo "<td>$Email</td>";
echo "<td>$DiviCodeU</td>";
echo "<td>$DeptCode</td>";
echo "<td>$Position</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
?></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id = "btnOkay1" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 10%">OK</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 10%">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnOkay1").click(function(){
     var arr = []; 
     $.each($('input[id="checkbox1"]:checked'), function(){
     arr.push($(this).val());
     });

     document.getElementById("PRRqName").value += arr.join("; ");
     document.getElementById("PRRqMail").value += arr.join("; ");
     document.getElementById("PRRqDept").value += arr.join("; ");
     document.getElementById("PRRqDivi").value += arr.join("; ");
     document.getElementById("PRRqPosi").value += arr.join("; ");
     });
     });
```

I expected that when I click checkbox in popup box data, click ok button the data of 5 will fill up in the 5 field which is name, email, department code, division code and position.

Comment: `arr.push($(this).val());` just pushes the value of the checkbox. If you want to get the values from the other tds, you need to select those tds.

Comment: already add different code to get the values, but it still not work..

Comment: In that case please [edit] the question to show what you tried, then we can help you to fix it.